# RewriteRule for URL to redirect from folder

Tags: php, linux, apache

currently, I have this simple rule to eliminate the need of php extensions in URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I need to add a new rule which only applies to one URL `Http://www.example.com/my-folder/$myFile`
I need to rewrite every request to my-folder to this url `Http://www.example.com/my-folder.php?file=$myFile`

Thank You

Comment: Try RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ $1.php?file=$2 I'm not sure about any starting / though so check you rewrite log

Comment: just out of curiosity, currently if I http://www.example.com//bob it goes to /bob.php and if bob.php doesn't exist it goes to /bob.php.php etc....

Comment: `RewriteRule ^my-folder/(.*)$ my-folder.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: @Waygood If bob.php doesn't exist, this condition fails: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this immediately after `RewriteEngine on`:

```
RewriteRule ^/?my-folder/(.*)$ /my-folder.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]
```